# Which is the best third party library for Image manipulation in .Net?

Tags: .net, image-processing, image-manipulation, imagemagick

Which is the best third party library for **Image manipulation** in .Net?

I have tried **ImageMagick.Net** (http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/releases/view/30302). But it does not have all the wrappers available like **transformations** and **Overlaying with blending**.

Comment: Using "best" makes the question subjective. Can you reword it to explain exactly what features you want from the library. You've mentioned 2, but the "etc." is just going to invite answers giving personal favourites.

Comment: You guys are too quick to give questions downvotes. There's nothing wrong with this guys question. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I work at Atalasoft.

We just made our photo processing imaging SDK, DotImage Photo, free.  It has 2D transformations and overlays.  If you need more features, you can upgrade to DotImage Photo Pro or Document Imaging.

Download here: http://www.atalasoft.com/photofree

Feature matrix here: http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/feature-matrix

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this. However the price looks very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com) to do quite a lot of image manipulation.  Quite an expansive and mature library.